# Why do I get this NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a twitter-copy and right now I'm trying to show all the posts from the users an other user is following. I'm new at ruby and rails, so i might be doing this a really weird way..

These are the files I have:

**session#home.html.erb**

```
<h2 class='User_Header'> Home <h2>

<%= link_to "New Post", controller: "posts", action: "new" %>
<%= link_to "Log Out", :controller => "sessions", :action => "logout" %>
<%= show_tweets("following") %>
```

**sessions_helper**

```
module SessionsHelper

    def show_tweets(opt)
        if opt == "following"
            @sub = Subscription.where("userID = ?", @current_user.id)
            @post = Post.where("user_id = ?", @sub.followingID)

            render partial: 'shared/follower_tweets'
        end
    end

    def show_tweet(s)
        @post = Post.where("user_id = ?", s.id)
        render partial: 'shared/tweet'
    end

    def tweet_username(p)
        @username = User.where("id = ?", p.user_id) 
        Rails.logger.debug @username.inspect
        render partial: 'shared/user'
    end
end
```

**_follower_tweets.html.erb**

```
<h2>Tweets</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Tweet</th>
    </tr>

    <% div_for(@post, class: 'post') do %>
        <td><%= tweet_username(@post) %></td>
        <td><%= @post.content %></td>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

**_user.html.erb**

```
<%= @username %>
```

**session.rb**

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base  
    attr_accessible :content, :user_id, :followingID, :userID
end
```

***Error***

app/views/sessions/home.html.erb where line #9 raised:

```
undefined method `followingID' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fd74b66f8a8>
```

Comment: Your `Subscription` model does not have a method called `followingID`.

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of followingID the subscription. I have a table in the db where i save all subscriptions, followingID is a column in that table

Comment: Have you added `attr_accessible :followingID` to your `Subscription` model?

Comment: yes I have. But, am I event trying to get the value the right way?

Comment: Please post the contents of your model.

Comment: added it. not much in it though

Comment: Thanks, not much but enough to identify the problem. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you have `followingID` on your `Session` model instead of `Subscription` model. Should be something like the following:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :followingID
end
```

However, the problem is bigger than that. You must read about [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), then you would be able to do something like

```
@subs = @current_user.subscriptions
@posts = @current_user.posts
```

Answer (score 0):

check if your model's association is correct.  the messages indicates that there's an error about this.